# Linux Multiple IP Docker Specify Public IP

Tags: docker

```
ifconfig 

ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.168.0.7  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.168.0.7

ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.120.0.5  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.120.0.5
```

#### config route

```
echo "1 rt1" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.120.0.1 src 10.120.0.5 dev ens5 table rt1
ip route add default via 10.120.0.1 dev ens5 table rt1
ip rule add from 10.120.0.5/20 table rt1
ip rule add to 10.120.0.5/20 table rt1

docker network create network1 --driver bridge --subnet 192.168.33.0/24
docker network create network2 --driver bridge --subnet 192.168.34.0/24

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.33.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.168.0.7
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.34.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.120.0.5
```

#### run docker

```
docker run -d --network network1 --name tm1 <Container Name>
docker run -d --network network2 --name tm2 <Container Name>
```

- Why tm1 container can access the network normally tm2 container cannot access the network
- What else do I need to do? Please help me